# How can I make my program faster for higher values?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, time

I'm solving the following codechef problem from a couple of days :- https://www.codechef.com/NOV16/problems/ALEXTASK

After a lot of hours of thinking I came up with the following solution :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t, n, i, flag;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        long a[n], time;

        for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            scanf("%ld", &a[i]);

        time = 1;
        flag = 0;

        while(1)
        {
            for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if(time % a[i] == 0)
                    flag++;

                if(flag == 2)
                    break;
            }

            if(flag == 2)
                break;

            else
            {
                time++;
                flag = 0;
            }
        }

        printf("%ld\n", time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm able to get accepted for smaller values of array a[i] i.e. a[i] <= 1000 but for larger values of array a[i] like a[i] <= 10^9 the time limit of 1 second is exceeding.

I thought a lot about ways to improve the time complexity but I'm unable to do so.

So, can anyone help me in improving my program ?

Comment: `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` -->> `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` for a start.

Comment: @wildplasser what difference does it make ?

Comment: ...or `long a[n+1]`

Comment: @wildplasser I did changed this thing but still it isn't getting accepted.

Comment: Your program reads and processes a lot of data if you read 10^9 numbers. IO takes time, and I wouldn't expect a program to use less than one second to read and process a billion numbers.  Keep in mind that 1/10^9 is .001 microsecond per number read. Unrealistic, IMHO.

Comment: @BjornA. 10^9 is not the number of elements in the array here but it is the value of the array element and the number of elements int the array is actually limited to 500.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken by the text of the problem you just need the two smallest numbers and you have the solution if they are the same, multiply both first otherwise. No, can't be that simple, or can it?